# sonar does not report status on github pull request

Tags: github, sonarqube

It seems that sonar no longer report for my pull requests. In october, it was working: https://github.com/edemo/PDEngine/pull/113

That one was using 7.4.0, which is later than 7.2.0, for which some kind of deprecation was announced here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrade-notes/

Today it does not report: https://github.com/edemo/PDEngine/pull/118
it uses 7.7.0, and no change in the build environment I am aware of.
I have specifically checked that none of the files in the repo which have anything to do with sonar have any relevant changes.

Where should I look for the problem's cause?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the change is in github. Adding Sonarcloud GitHub app to the organization solved the problem. It is another check than the old one, so I had to update the branch protection rules as well.